# Software or websites for finding people with similar interests

Tags: search-engine, search, social-networks, recommendation-engine

i'm looking for software or websites where i can enter my interests (in my case for example: buddhism, astronomy, psychology) and find other people with similar interests

(The location doesn't matter, i'm not looking to connect with people locally, but rather online. Also the site itself does not need to have a chat feature, just contact info)

What i'm looking for could be a software or website with a recommendation engine similar to getting movie recommendations, but the software or website could also be much simpler by just matching by interests. (I'm also open to other approaches if there are alternatives)

Grateful for help and with kind regards,
Tord

Comment: Do you want to build such a site (so you look for software that allows you to do this) or do you want to use such a site (so you look for a site where you actually can find people right now)? In the latter case, this question would be off-topic here.

Comment: A little bit more detail would be helpful. Do you have a budget? What operating system? What do you want to happen after you find someone with similar interests,  are you looking for just sending messages back and forth? Video chat,  or maybe voice chat? Or do you want to just simply view a person's "profile" where there's links to all their social media,  or whatever else,  with no built in chatting features? Do you want to be able to "add friends", or just have a more of a one-time session with another person? Do you want a lightweight program, or something with a bunch of features?

Comment: @sunyata are you looking for software that will give you instant access to people who share similar interests as you, or are you wanting to create your own network? No one can really give you an answer till you answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your question because I've been wanting to create a company / app solely to address this gap.  There is nothing in existence currently that will directly fill your need with excellence I must say, although I'm sure eventually it will come.  In the meantime, people are using the following primarily:

- [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/)
- [Sub-Reddits](http://reddit.com)
- [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/)
- [Quora](https://www.quora.com/)
- [Flipora](http://login.flipora.com/login.jsp)

.. Specifically, by browsing along topic / interest lines and then communicating and connecting with users who also express such interests ( RE: [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/drewhendricks/2014/10/16/are-interest-based-networks-the-way-of-the-future/) ).  And of course, there's interest-specific websites such as [Doximity](https://www.doximity.com/) and others which doesn't fulfill your requirements in full, but does help you connect to others if your interests just *happen* to align with a interest-specific social network.

There's also [Meetup](http://www.meetup.com/), which will directly help you find people in your area with similar interests, although through "meetups" which may not be what you're looking for, but again would help.

Along the same lines as Meetup, the following websites / apps may also help, however I've not tried [these](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-tools-find-awesome-people-similar-interests/):

- [Groupspaces](http://groupspaces.com/)
- [MEETin](http://meetin.org/)
- [Smacktive](http://www.smacktive.com/)

Finally the app landscape is constantly changing in regards to helping with this question:

- http://appcrawlr.com/ios-apps/best-apps-people-with-common-interests

From this list, the new app Highlight looks appealing:

- http://highlig.ht/

Comment: Grat answer. More material:

* http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-tools-find-awesome-people-similar-interests/
* https://www.quora.com/Social-Discovery/How-do-you-find-people-with-similar-interests